# Php if session declare variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem, I want to assign a value to a variable according to session:

Here my simple code:

```
<?php
    if ( $_SESSION['admin_level'] == 10 ) { 
        $myvar = 'newclient';
    } elseif ( $_SESSION['admin_level'] == 11 ) {
        $myvar = 'oldclient';
    }
?>
```

in this way, I can make a query:

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM client where client_status='".$myvar."'";
```

Unfortunately I can not declare the variable and fails. Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you used `session_start();` before any other output? You say it fails - what error do you see?

Comment: if the error is in the query, MySql said that no results, but that can not read the value of the variable. Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: You need to give more information about the error. The problem can be that the session was not started, like comment above. You can print the value of you session variable with echo function to help you find the problem.  Another consideration is that your if doesnt have an else statement.

Comment: Well then the error is surrounding the line with `mysql_num_rows()`. Please post the code surrounding your SQL query as that is more relevant

Comment: The problem is PHP because I can not see the result in Echo. see: <?php if($_SESSION['admin_level']==10) 
        { 
        echo "LEVEL 10";} 
        
        elseif($_SESSION['admin_level']==11)
           {
           echo "LEVEL 11";} 
           
?>
This Works

Comment: <?php
$myvar = 'newclient';
?>  ... and the qry goes well, as I can declare the variable as the session? I think the syntax is what's wrong, I need a ECHO? as if ($ _ SESSION [ 'admin_level'] == 10) {
     ECHO $ myvar = 'newclient';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear about question. as far as i understood check the below code

```
 <?php
   session_start(); // this is the first thing to do

   if(isset($_SESSION['admin_level'])){
        $_SESSION['admin_level']=10; //Set admin level if not available
    }

   $var=($_SESSION['admin_level']==10)?"newclient":"oldclient";


   $qry="SELECT * FROM client where client_status='".$var."'";
```

Comment: Thank you. now, this works? <?php
session_start(); // this is the first thing to do

if(isset($_SESSION['admin_level']))
 {
     $var=($_SESSION['admin_level']==10)?"value1";}
     elseif{
     $var=($_SESSION['admin_level']==11)?"value2";}
?>

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ';'   * $var=($_SESSION['admin_level']==10)?"value1";}*

Comment: You need to define default value. its a shortcut of IF.. ELSE.. $var=($_SESSION['admin_level']==10)?"value1":"value2";

Comment: I understand, but what happens when I have more users? admin_level 11,22,31, I want to assign a variable to read reports by user